# Replace photo diode and phototransistor with an IrDA chip

Tags: serial, infrared, photodiode, phototransistor

We have a circuit that communicate optically with a symmetrical circuit (exactly the same circuit at the other side). The circuit is based on a phototransistor [SFH 320](https://www.tme.eu/Document/bee431c3a37943667d866d47da091570/SFH320.pdf), a photodiode [ZTHI55WA-3-SGM](https://www.sunledusa.com/products/spec/XZTHI55W-3.pdf), and is receiving 3V3 TX/RX signal from a microcontroller, then communicating with the product (which contains exactly the same circuit). The communication is working perfectly without issue at 115200 baud.

We want to reduce the PCB dimensions and for that we are planning to replace the two circuits FLAG_TX and FLAG_RX (on the joined circuit) with a single chip [TFBS4711-TT1](https://www.vishay.com/docs/82633/tfbs4711.pdf). Please note that the circuit on the product we are communicating with will remain the same (photo transistor and photo diode).
Has anyone used such chip (IrDA one) for communicating with photo transistor and photo diode? Do you have any examples documentation?

[image: circuit]

Comment: Photodiode : ZTHI55WA-3-SGM https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-5891723/SFH%20320_EN.pdf
Phototransitor: SFH320 https://www.tme.eu/Document/bee431c3a37943667d866d47da091570/SFH320.pdf

Comment: Hi @MiNiMe actually the SHF320 is the phototransistor with the right datasheet and here the datasheet of the ZTHI55WA-3-SGM https://www.sunledusa.com/products/spec/XZTHI55W-3.pdf. I ll update the description

Comment: Sorry, a search for ZTHI55WA-3-SGM first brought up images for some LED light. My mistake, I thought you hadn't had your morning coffee.

Comment: SHF 320 have a range of 450 - 1150 and a peak sensitivity at 980 nm, ZTHI55WA-3-SGM peak intensity is at 880, ±50(?) nm, and IrDA is specified at 850–900 nm. Your current setup isn't perfectly matched but works, so odds are that using the new module will work too since the SFH seems to be rather 'forgiving'.